# How to get product type from product entity (Drupal commerce)?

Tags: drupal-8, commerce

I'm getting product object with a view. How to get its type?

```
$view = Views::getView('get_all_products');
$view->execute();
foreach ($view->result as $row) { // products
  $product = $row->_entity;
  $product = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($product); // Translating it
  $productType = $product-> ????
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it better solution:

```
$product_type = $product->bundle();
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit insane way I've found is:

```
$productType = $product->get("type")[0]->get("target_id")->getValue();
```

Anyone has a better solution?